# Difficulties with a proof and log sum inequality

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Hello I have some problems with this proof :

The idea is to use the log sum inequality to prove this where $a,b,c,d,e$ are positive real numbers:

$$\frac{a+c+1}{b+c+1}+\frac{b+d+1}{c+d+1}+\frac{c+e+1}{d+e+1}+\frac{d+a+1}{e+a+1}+\frac{e+b+1}{a+b+1}\geq 5$$

To begin we have this :

$ \frac{a+c+1}{b+c+1}log((\frac{a+c+1}{b+c+1})\frac{e-0.5+2(b+c)}{a+c+1})=\frac{a+c+1}{b+c+1}log(\frac{e-0.5+2(b+c)}{b+c+1})$

With:

$log(2)< log(\frac{e-0.5+2(b+c)}{b+c+1})\leq log(e-0.5)$

So with that we can apply the log sum inequality with :

$a_1=\frac{a+c+1}{b+c+1}$   and   $b_1=\frac{e-0.5+2(b+c)}{a+c+1}$

$a_2=\frac{b+d+1}{d+c+1}$   and   $b_2=\frac{e-0.5+2(d+c)}{b+d+1}$

$a_3=\frac{e+c+1}{d+e+1}$   and   $b_3=\frac{e-0.5+2(d+e)}{e+c+1}$

$a_4=\frac{a+d+1}{e+a+1}$   and   $b_4=\frac{e-0.5+2(e+a)}{a+d+1}$

$a_5=\frac{e+b+1}{b+a+1}$   and   $b_5=\frac{e-0.5+2(b+a)}{e+b+1}$

With $\sum_{i=1}^{5}a_i=a$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{5}b_i=b$

So we get :

$$\sum_{i=1}^{5}a_ilog(\frac{a_i}{b_i})\geq alog(\frac{a}{b})$$

But we have this two facts :

$log(\frac{a_i}{b_i})\leq log(e-0.5)$

And

$log(\frac{a}{b})\geq log(2)$

We get this :

$$log(e-0.5)a\geq\sum_{i=1}^{5}a_ilog(\frac{a_i}{b_i})\geq alog(\frac{a}{b})\geq alog(2)$$

So we have $a\geq \frac{1}{log(e-0.5)-log(2)}$

But it's wrong but I don't know where is the mistake.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a=kx$,... and similar, where $k>0$.

Thus, we need to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{x+z+\frac{1}{k}}{y+z+\frac{1}{k}}\geq5$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{x-y}{y+z+\frac{1}{k}}\geq0,$$
which for $k\rightarrow+\infty$ gives
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{x-y}{y+z}\geq0,$$ which is open.